# How to store a String in JSF with no reference to the method?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I want to store a ID(String) in a Variable in my Facelets file.
I tried to use ui:param but every time I use this param it just invoke the method again and I have different values.

```
<ui:param name="ids" value="#{models.genId()}"/>

public static String genId() {
        String key = getSaltString();

        while(modelMap.containsKey(key))
            key = getSaltString();

        modelMap.put(key, new DataTableModel());

        return key;
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
<c:set var="datatable1key" value="#{models.genId()}" scope="session" />
```

Comment: UI's don't "store" variables, databases do.

Comment: The param is just not a cache. If you want things to be called once during the view, use a `c:set`

Comment: @Kukeltje i try c:set

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks i use now c.set